# Rails find objects without an ID in a serialized array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am using rails 3.2 and postgresql, and creating site wide announcements. I have a column that I've put all of the IDs of users who have already seen the announcement. How do I find all announcements that do not include a user's id?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
class User
  def announcements
    Announcement.where(":hidden_users_ids DOES NOT INCLUDE ?", self.id)
  end
end
```

hidden_users_ids is a text column that I have serialized an array into.

I want this method to return all announcements that do not have a user's id in the hidden_users_ids array.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you change the schema? Looking inside serialized data inside the database is a bit of a nightmare, especially if you're using the default YAML serialization. Is this Rails3 or Rails4?

Comment: I could easily change the schema, what would be a better way of doing this? I assume I'm using the default rails 3 serialization. Just have 'serialize :hidden_users_ids'. Thanks @muistooshort

Comment: (1) Forget that `serialize` exists. (2) Use a separate association table to store the (announcement_id,seen_by_id) pairs and a `has_many` association in Rails (or add the `postgres_ext` gem and use a real native PostgreSQL array column). (3) Search for "has_many" and "not in" ActiveRecord questions, this has almost certainly been answered before. (4) Profit. Gotta' run now but I'll have a look later if someone doesn't get to it first.

Comment: Thanks, I've gotten the postgres_ext to work where its finding every announcement that has the user's ID now I just have to find the negative of that. I'm done for now, but I'll try that later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go the array route (which your comments suggest), then the [`@>` and `&&` operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) will give you the "does include" side of things:

> **Operator**: `@>`
>   **Description**: contains
>   **Example**: `ARRAY[1,4,3] @> ARRAY[3,1]`
>   **Result**: `t`
>
> **Operator**: `&&`
>   **Description**: overlap (have elements in common)
>   **Example**: `ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1]`
>   **Result**: `t`

If the array on the RHS only has one element then `@>` and `&&` will be equivalent.

That means that you can do things like this:

```
Announcement.where("hidden_users_ids @> array[:id]", :id => self.id)
```

to find the announcements that have been seen by `self`. If you want to find the announcements that have **not** been seen by `self`, then just negate the logic:

```
Announcement.where("not hidden_users_ids @> array[:id]", :id => self.id)
# ------------------^^^
```